# Docker build error "exec format error" when trying to install an docker image

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run

> sudo docker build -t myimage .

Into my raspberry pi4 and I get this error:

> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format

> error" The command '/bin/sh -c pip install flask' returned a non-zero
> code: 1

I have searched for this error and this is caused because the Dockerfile image that I want to use is for intel arhitecture but as you can know, Raspberry is on ARM arhitecture. I have searched how to convert the image to ARM arhitecture but this was without succes.
Does any of you have any ideea how to manage this ?

Here is the github that I tried to run(I have tried to run a test file for python 3.7): https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert an image from one architecture to another. You need to build it yourself, starting from the first image in the hierarchy that does have a variant with the right architecture.

In your case you would need to clone [uwsgi-nginx-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker) to your RPi, try to build the image using `docker-images/python3.7.dockerfile`. If that works you would then need to clone [uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker), change file `docker-images/python3.8.dockerfile` to use the image you build in the previous step, instead of the one it uses now, and then try to build that one.